# Functions being exponentially repeated in my js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running a site using Node, Express and MongoDB.  I generate containers after an ajax call to get the data to fill them with, and each of the containers has a button which makes another ajax call specific to a recipe it's getting detailed information on. The first Time I do this it works perfectly, but if i get details for a 2nd one it executes the function 3 times instead of one, and if I do it for a 3rd container it runs it 9 times and so on.  I'm fairly new with Jquery and perhaps It's a misunderstanding of how the events work. the problems also occurs with the saveRecipe function.

global.js

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $('.details').popover({"trigger": "manual", "html":"true"});
  $('.details').click(get_data_for_popover_and_display);
  $('.save-favorite').on('click', saveRecipe );
});

(function ($) {
    $('#search').on('click', function (e) {
      // remove resultset if this has already been run
      $('.recipes').empty();

      var recipeName = document.getElementById('recipeName').value;
      var recipeNameString = '&q=' + recipeName;

      var ingredientHtml = '&allowedIngredient[]=';
      var ingredientsArray = document.getElementById('ingredients').value.split(",");
      var ingredientsString = '';
      if (ingredientsArray[0] !== ""){
        for (i = 0; i < ingredientsArray.length; i++){
          ingredientsArray[i] = ingredientHtml + ingredientsArray[i].trim();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ingredientsArray.length; i++){
          ingredientsString += ingredientsArray[i];
        }
      }

      var excludedIngredientHtml = '&excludedIngredient[]=';
      var excludedIngredientsArray = document.getElementById('ingredientsExclude').value.split(",");
      var excludedIngredientsString = '';
      if (excludedIngredientsArray[0] !== ""){
        for (i = 0; i < excludedIngredientsArray.length; i++){
          excludedIngredientsArray[i] = excludedIngredientHtml + excludedIngredientsArray[i].trim();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < excludedIngredientsArray.length; i++){
          excludedIngredientsString += excludedIngredientsArray[i];
        }
      }

      var dietHtml = '';
      if(document.getElementById('lacto-veg').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=388^Lacto vegetarian';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('ovo-veg').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=389^Ovo vegetarian';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('paleo').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=403^Paleo';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('pescetarian').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=390^Pescetarian';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('vegan').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=386^vegan';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('vegetarian').checked){
        dietHtml += '&allowedDiet[]=387^Lacto-ovo vegetarian';
      }

      var allergyHtml = '';
      if(document.getElementById('dairy-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=396^Dairy-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('egg-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=397^Egg-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('gluten-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=393^gluten-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('peanut-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=394^Peanut-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('seafood-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=398^Seafood-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('seseme-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=399^Seseme-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('sulfite-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=401^Sulfite-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('tree-nut-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=395^Tree Nut-Free';
      }
      if(document.getElementById('wheat-free').checked){
        allergyHtml += '&allowedAllergy[]=392^Wheat-Free';
      }

      var apiHtml = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=&_app_key=' +recipeNameString;
      if (ingredientsString){
        apiHtml += ingredientsString;
      }
      if (excludedIngredientsString){
        apiHtml += excludedIngredientsString;
      }
      if (dietHtml){
        apiHtml += dietHtml;
      }
      if (allergyHtml){
        apiHtml += allergyHtml;
      }
      apiHtml += '&requirePictures=true';
      apiHtml = apiHtml.replace(' ', '%20');

      $.getJSON(apiHtml, function (json) {
        var recipes = [],
            $recipes;

        $.each(json, function (key, val) {
          if (key === "matches"){
            for (i = 0; i < val.length ; i++) {
              if (i%3 === 0){
                recipes.push('<div class="row">');
              }
              recipes.push('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">');
              recipes.push('<div class="thumbnail">' + '<img src="'+ val[i].imageUrlsBySize[90] + '" alt="' + val[i].recipeName + '" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 300px; width: 100%; display: block;"/>');
              recipes.push('<div class="caption">' + '<h3 class="caption-text">' + val[i].recipeName + '</h3>');
              recipes.push('<p class="caption-text">' + val[i].sourceDisplayName + '</p>');
              recipes.push('<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary details" data-toggle="popover" title="' + val[i].recipeName + '" value="' + val[i].id + '"> Details </button> ');
              recipes.push('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-favorite" method="post" action="saveFavorite" value="' + val[i].id + '"> Favorite </button></p>');
              recipes.push('</div></div></div>');
              if ((i+1)%3 === 0){
                recipes.push('</div>');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      if (recipes.length < 1) {
      recipes.push('<p>No results for parameters, try again!</p>');
      }
      $recipes = $('<div />').appendTo('.recipes');
      $recipes.append(recipes.join(''));
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}(jQuery));


get_data_for_popover_and_display = function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if(el.hasClass('recipe-loaded')){
  }
  else {
    var _data = $(this).attr('alt');
    var recipeUrl = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/' + this.value + '?_app_id=&_app_key=';
    var recipeHtml = '';
    var ingredientsHtml = '';
    var nutritionHtml = '';
    var ratingHtml = '';
    var servingsHtml = '';
    var sourceHtml = '';

    $.getJSON(recipeUrl, function (json) {
         $.each(json, function (key, val) {
           if (key === "ingredientLines"){
             ingredientsHtml = '<h4>Ingredients:</h4><ul>';
             for (i = 0; i < val.length ; i++){
               ingredientsHtml += ('<li>' + val[i] + '</li>');
             }
             ingredientsHtml += '</ul>';
           }
           if (key === "nutritionEstimates"){
             if(val.length > 0){
             nutritionHtml = 'Cal. per Serving: ' + val[0].value + '<br>';
             }
           }
           if (key === "rating"){
             ratingHtml += 'Rating: ' + val + '</p>';
           }
           if (key === "numberOfServings"){
             servingsHtml += '<p>Servings: ' + val + '<br>';
           }
           if (key === "source"){
             sourceHtml += '<p><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary details" href="'+ val.sourceRecipeUrl +'" >Source</a>';
           }
         })
       recipeHtml += ingredientsHtml;
       recipeHtml += servingsHtml;
       recipeHtml += nutritionHtml;
       recipeHtml += ratingHtml;
       recipeHtml += sourceHtml;
       el.attr('data-content', recipeHtml).success(el.popover('toggle'));
       el.addClass('recipe-loaded');
     });
  }
};

function saveRecipe(){
  var recipeUrl = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/' + this.value + '?_app_id=3e5b7dbe&_app_key=1d681685a57dac07e6df0b1c0df38de6';
  var json = $.getJSON(recipeUrl, function (data){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       url: '/saverecipe',
       dataType: 'JSON'
   });
 });
};
```

Comment: Hi Bradley, and welcome to SO. In its current state I would downvote your question, because you're simply dumping a large amount of code and ask us to solve your problem. While you can obviously do this and possibly even get the answer you want, SO is not a "free code review and bugfixing site". Please try to isolate your problem, i.e. in which specific part of the code do you think it occurs, what have you tried to isolate and fix the problem, etc. This will a) help others help you faster and b) not put the burden of understanding all your code on the rest of us, which is simply good manners

Comment: Thanks for your input fresskoma, I'll try to be more concise in the future as  I could have narrowed it down to just the saveRecipe function and the $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){}); portion.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$('.details').click(get_data_for_popover_and_display);
```

hooks up a **new** event handler on all `.detail` elements that will call `get_data_for_popover_and_display`, **even if** that element already has an event handler calling `get_data_for_popover_and_display`. Same with:

```
$('.save-favorite').on('click', saveRecipe );
```

So since `get_data_for_popover_and_display` (at least) does another ajax call, which will add another handler, you'll get increasing numbers of handlers over time.

It's exactly like this:

```js
function clickHandler() {
  console.log(+new Date(), "Clicked");
  clickComplete();
}
function clickComplete() {
  $("#btn").on("click", clickHandler);
}
clickComplete();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So: Only add a handler if you haven't already done so. Perhaps keep track in jQuery's `data` store:

```js
function clickHandler() {
  console.log(+new Date(), "Clicked");
  clickComplete();
}
function clickComplete() {
  $("#btn").filter(function() {
    return !$(this).data("hasClick");
  })
  .on("click", clickHandler)
  .data("hasClick", true);
}
clickComplete();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```